# Why use abstract class instead of interface if no methods are implemented

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular2 in its file `core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks.ts` [declares](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks.ts#L69) class as abstract

```
export abstract class OnInit { abstract ngOnInit(): void; }
```

why not declare it as interface since it doesn't have implementation?

Comment: because interfaces don't exist and so you cannot inject them; you can inject to an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces don't exist in java-script; So, presumably, using abstract classes (that don't have any member implementations) is a useful way to have that "contract" have a real type at run time. One possible use would be for dependency injection.

Comment: thanks, what you're saying is that `abstract class` is compiled into JS function, while `interface` is not?

Comment: yes, pretty much; or to a es6 class. Interfaces don't emit any code unfortunately; effectively makes interfaces somewhat painful to use when you want to use DI; [see here for workaround example](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS#step-2-declare-dependencies-using-the-injectable--inject-decorators)

Comment: This doesn't explain why hooks are classes and not interfaces. They are used as interfaces exclusively.

Comment: @estus, I've asked a bunch of questions regarding angular2 implementation details, and I've received no answer. So I think there won't be for this one as well. I've accepted the answer that at least explained what _could_ be the rationale

Comment: @Maximus There are not so many people on SO who participate in A2 development, so the chances to get firsthand information are little. There's no use for abstract hook classes to my knowledge and they are used only as interfaces, most likely they were made classes and not interfaces for future use (they occupy space in bundle but can be tree-shaken).

Comment: @estus, yeah, that's the problem for those willing to get into sources :) I can't figure out what's the best place to get that information. I asked on github using issue, but it got closed with reference to stackoverflow. what's `tree-shaken`?

Comment: @Maximus Possibly gitter.im and google groups. It's the action of [tree-shaking](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#tree-shaking). Unused classes can be omitted from the bundle.

Comment: @estus, yeah, thanks. I've read `build your own angular` for angular1 and decided to take what's inside angular2, but it's certainly going to be a lot harder)